# BCP.exe Out not identifying table so it can be written to a file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bcp

When I run:

```
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell 'bcp [ServerName\Instance].[DB_Name].[dbo].[r] out
 "C:\0\folder\subfolder\filename.csv" -c -t "|" -T'
```

I get the error message:

```
A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options.
```

My goal is to simply export the contents of the table named r to a pipe delimited file. The line is used multiple times in the script with a different output file name. The table r is dropped and recreated multiple times with different content each time from a different table (not in a loop or cursor). The error occurs at the first time the code block above is run.

- This is on SQL Server 2014, Management Studio 12.0.5000.
- This script ran just fine when the volume storing the DB was mounted
  on another machine running SQL Server 2014 as well.
- I have run:
  `EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1`
  `EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1`
  along with:
  `RECONFIGURE`
- I am the DB owner.
- The local path "C:\0\folder\subfolder\" exists.
- I can successfully select and view the table contents with the query:

  ```
  `Select * From [ServerName\Instance].[DB_Name].[dbo].[r]`
  ```
- Prior to adding the code `[ServerName\Instance]`, the error msg said that it couldn't open a connection.
- There are three results that show up when I search for the error message above and none of them address my issue.

Comment: You need to give the server & instance name with the `-S` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @James Z noted you need to specify `server_name[\instance_name]`. Also you need to remove `[ServerName\Instance].` before `[DB_Name]...`

Thus, you command should look like this:

```
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell 'bcp [DB_Name].[dbo].[r] out
 "C:\0\folder\subfolder\filename.csv" -c -t "|" -T -S ServerName\Instance'
```

Comment: As a side note the first time I tried the solution above, I had [ServerName\Instance] including the square brackets. Removing the square brackets and the solution by Albert and JamesZ worked fine.